# Finding Gradient vector in spherical polars

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Can someone give a step by step explanation of how to determine the gradient vector in spherical coordinates please? I've looked on several sites for explanations, but I don't understand their methods. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is starting with $$\begin{cases}x = r \cos \theta \cos \varphi \\ y = r \cos \theta \sin \varphi \\ z = r \sin \theta\end{cases},$$ and writing $\frac{\partial}{\partial x},\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$ in terms of $\frac{\partial}{\partial r},\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial \varphi}$. For example, if you have $f = f(x(r,\theta,\varphi),y(r,\theta,\varphi),z(r,\theta,\varphi))$, we get, by using the chain rule: $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial r} = \cos \theta \cos \varphi \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\cos \theta \sin \varphi \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}+\sin \theta \frac{\partial f}{\partial z},$$ and since $f$ was arbitrary: $$\frac{\partial }{\partial r} = \cos \theta \cos \varphi \frac{\partial }{\partial x}+\cos \theta \sin \varphi \frac{\partial }{\partial y}+\sin \theta \frac{\partial }{\partial z}.$$

In the same fashion you will compute $\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial \varphi}$. So you have a linear system with unknowns $\frac{\partial}{\partial x},\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$. Solve that system, and write $\nabla = \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x},\frac{\partial}{\partial y},\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\right)$ in your new coordinates.

Comment: How do I solve the system easily though? It looks horrible to invert the 3x3 matrix

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know a way that avoids inverting the matrix. What I can tell you, though, is that $$\frac{\partial(x,y,z)}{\partial(r,\theta,\varphi)} = r \sin \theta$$